# Importing XML to WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, xml, wordpress

My client is using WordPress as CMS but want's to deliver their posts (in their case property's) trough a XML feed.

Is it possible to get the info from that XML feed and import it to WordPress as posts?

This is what my feed looks like: http://vrds.nl/test.xml

Hoping for help!

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few plugins that do this. Perhaps one of them fits what you want to do.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ben! Could you point more in the direction of what plugin should work best for me?

Comment: Do you know what the source of the XML is? Does it come from a Blogger export? You can always convert the XML into a csv file and import using the CSV Importer plugin. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/csv-importer/

Comment: No its not from "blogger" or something like that. How could I convert it to CSV? Love to know more about that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

My company made a plugin that can do exactly this.

It is called WP All Import - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-all-import/ - it can import XML in any format, download images (something you'll probably need if you are importing properties), and works with any theme.